# Can we add additional fields in CollaborationGroup and CollaborationGroupMember

Tags: community

I have a requirement to create additional fields to add geolocation on community group and define type of member.
Though I cannot find this object to add fields in my developer org,
is it possible by any way to create fields on it or a new object seems only otion.

Please help!

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CollaborationGroup object is not customizable and does not support the custom field feature that exists in some other objects.

This is one of those objects that skirts the boundary between configuration objects (like PublicGroups, Queues, Profiles) and data objects (Account, Contact, etc...).

I don't know how desperately you need to implement this...but the best you'd be able to do is have some geolocation data in one of the publicly editable fields that allow you to store information about the group (like Description, Information Body, Information Title).

[and this gets ugly now]

You could then use a CollaborationGroup trigger so that once a string was appended on the end of that group, it was always re-appended on every edit. Or if updated, appended with the updated data.

You'd get **absolutely zero** benefit of the standard geolocation features available when using the geocoded datatype fields you might use in another object such as being able to query by radius (so cool that). But you'd get the geo coordinates at least stored within.

Like I said...ugly.

On the theme of ugly hacks. If this is really a matter of visualization of the Collab Groups data, there is always the workaround of storing enough representative data to a secondary custom object that *has* the ability to use geolocation fields, then drive your vizualization off of that data. You'd want to store the original CollaborationGroup id in a field as well so you could refer back. You could again use the CollaborationGroup trigger functionality to keep it in sync.

But here, you burn a custom object for your trouble...so a definite downside as well.

Sounds like an idea ripe for Idea Exchange, though: custom fields on Collaboration Group.

Comment: Peter - I  have designed it using trigger and another object and no proper relation between objects was costing extra code, but I want to use Geolocation functionality so it sounds only viable solution for the time. Thanks for the inputs!